# Rotate an input table without rotating page

Tags: tables, landscape

I get an input file `table1.tex` which contains a table  (i.e. `table1.tex` starts with `\begin{table} ... \{table}`)

I would like to print this table in landscape mode, but without rotating the page.

**I tried:**

```
\begin{landscape}
\input{table1.tex}
\end{landscape}
```

but this does rotate the entire page.

Comment: If this table fits on a single page, maybe the `sidewaystable` environment is what you're after (from the `rotating` package).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to rotate a table, try using `adjustbox`. Btw, your input file has to contain a `tabular` (not `table`) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{rotate=270}
\input{table1.tex} 
%table1.tex contains a tabular environment
%Input example:
%\begin{tabular}{l|l}
%This is & a table \\
%\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

If you really need to use a `table` environment (with captions and references), you can try the code below (again, avoiding the `table` to appear inside the input file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{yourcaptions}\end{minipage}},rotate=270,center,float=table}
\input{table1.tex}
%Input example:
%\begin{tabular}{l|l}
%This is & a table \\
%\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```